# Godot odd behavior with on_body_entered and on_body_exited

Tags: signals, collision, godot

I have a KinematicBody2D (player) and an Area2D (ladder). With the following code I get clean enter and exit events that happen as the player touches and leaves the Area2D object e.g. touch Area2D and a single "enter" prints. Move back and a single "exit" prints.

```
func _on_Ladder_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
        print("enter")

func _on_Ladder_body_exited(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
        print("exit")
```

with this code things go wrong:

```
func _on_Ladder_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
        set_collision_layer_bit(0, false)
        print("enter")

func _on_Ladder_body_exited(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
        set_collision_layer_bit(0, true)
        print("exit")
```

I get an entered event immediately followed by an exit event as soon as the player touches the Area2D. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
Godot version 3.4.2

Comment: Godot is doing what you are telling it to do. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to turn off collisions so the player can pass the object and re-enable them when he passes and leaves the Area2D object. If I just turn off the bit in on_entered, and not try to re-enable in on_exited, I can walk past the Area2D object. Trying to re-enable the bit in on on_exited fires both signals together by just touching the Area2D object. This doesn't seem to be correct behavior based on the first chunk of code I posted.

Comment: The `Area2D` does not prevent physic bodies from passing. In fact, that is the point of using an `Area2D`. If the ladder is preventing the `KinematicBody2D` to pass, you did that by other means, disable those other means, not the `Area2D`. I cannot tell you how to do that, because I don't know how the ladder is stopping the `KinematicBody2D`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the Area2D has a child node of type CollisionShape2D that gives the Area2D its shape and to let me know when the player touches the ladder. The ladder itself is a scene converted to a tileset. the scene had  collision objects on the ladder rungs. I am very new to Godot, am I missing something obvious? Thanks again...

Comment: Did put a `StaticBody2D` for the ladder? Or did you make the ladder with a `TileMap` where the tiles have collision? Those would be the simplest ways to make the ladder not passable. And that would be the collision you want to disable, not the collision with the `Area2D`. Edit: I guessing it is the collision in the tiles.

Comment: Sorry that I am being so thick headed. The ladder was made with a Tilemap where parts of the ladder tile have one way collision objects of type CollisionShape2D. The ladder and rungs (with the collision objects) are not wider than the Area2D object. For now I will recheck my tilemap and see if the problem is there.  THanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godot is doing what you are telling it to do.

The call `set_collision_layer_bit(0, false)` would be disabling the collision between the `KinematicBody2D` and the `Area2D` which means they would no longer be colliding. And since they stop colliding, you get a `"body_exited"` signal.

---

> I want to turn off collisions so the player can pass the object and re-enable them when he passes and leaves the Area2D object

The `Area2D` do not stop physics bodies (`StaticBody2D`, `KinematicBody2D`, `RigidBody`). There must be something else doing that. For example, if you added a `StaticBody2D` to the ladder, or made it with a `TileMap` where the tiles have collision, those could stop your `KinematicBody2D`.

---

I think the simplest approach would be to put the `Area2D` in a different collision layer, so you can disable the collision that stops the `KinematicBody2D` without disabling the `Area2D`.

Other options to disable collisions include:

- Disabling a `CollisionPolygon2D` or `CollisionShape2D` by setting `disabled` to `true`. Note: you cannot to do this while Godot is resolving collision response. To avoid that, use `set_deferred` to change the value of `disabled`.
- Adding a collision exception by calling `add_collision_exception_with`. Use `remove_collision_exception_with` to remove the exception. This is a more fine grained tool that should be used sparingly (if you are adding lots of exception, prefer using collision layers and masks).

**Addendum**: An option for the `TileMap` is to have two version of the tile, one with the collision and one without it. And the swap them in runtime with `set_cell`. However, consider using a scene instead. In fact, you might want to set the cells in the designer and replace them with actual scenes in runtime. See [How to use SCENES in a TILEMAP(And 9 MORE TRICKS) | Godot Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mGa2m_qCPQ). *You may even do it only when the player gets nearby, see [How to create large Sidescrolling Map in Godot?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198659/10408).*